# jQuery array doesn't work after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery.timepicker plugin. ( link : http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/ )

Please refer code example below (it works)

```
var disableTime= [['12:30 PM', '1:00 PM'], ['11:30 AM', '12:00 PM']];


$("#InterviewTime").timepicker(

                            {
                                'minTime': '7:00am',
                                'maxTime': '9:00pm',
                                'disableTimeRanges': disableTime
                            }
                            );
```

However, I need to fetch data for "disableTime" variable from the server via Ajax call. To do that I am preparing a c# string (in my ASP.NET MVC controller) in the same format as I have shown above in "disableTime" variable. I receive the formatted string in jQuery as Json string and then I convert the string to javascript array...as shown below

```
                var disableTime = jQuery.makeArray(data);
```

but this doesn't work

Any guess why it's not working ?

If I manually copy data via console.log(jQuery.makeArray(data)) and then assign hardcoded copied value to "disableTime" variable, it again works fine.

Here is the complete code

## MVC Controller

```
var outputStr = "[['12:30 PM', '1:00 PM'], ['11:30 AM', '12:00 PM']]";
return Json(outputStr, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

## JQuery

```
 $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetUnavailableTime", "Interview")',
                           type: 'GET',
                           data: { 'scheduledDate': scheduledDate, 'timeZone': timeZone},
                           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                           dataType: 'json',
                           success: function (data) {
                               var disableTime = jQuery.makeArray(data); 

                               $("#InterviewTime").timepicker(
                                {
                                    //'minTime': newtime,
                                    'minTime': '7:00am',
                                    'maxTime': '9:00pm',
                                    'disableTimeRanges': disableTime
                                }
                                );
                           },
                           error: function (xhr, err) {
                               alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                               alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                           }
                       });
```

Comment: Use fiddler/firebug to make sure your page is getting called. After that make sure that the returned JSON is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If `data` in your example is a JSON string, don't use `makeArray`. Use `JSON.parse(data)` instead. `makeArray` expects an object, not a string.

Note that the JSON must be valid JSON, meaning all strings must be contained within double quotes with properly escaped content and properly closed brackets. Run it through a JSON validator to verify that your script is receiving valid JSON.

Comment: thanks for the response. Json.Parse gives error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : I tried this statement :  var disableTime = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Make sure that your JSON uses double quotes, never single quotes. Use http://pro.jsonlint.com/ to verify that your string is actually valid JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You can use getJSON() since your page is returning JSON. getJSON will parse the JSON string automatically.

```
$.getJSON('yourURL', function (disableTime) {
    $("#InterviewTime").timepicker(
    {
        'minTime': '7:00am',
        'maxTime': '9:00pm',
        'disableTimeRanges': disableTime
    }
    );
});
```

Comment: this is Not working...